# JTable:Swing: Dynamic button name is not coming

Tags: java, swing

**I'm dynamically generated one new button for every row and i want that button name as Edit.
I'm getting that button but I'm not able to name the button as Edit,**

Based on this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm), here's what I tried:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */
public class JButtonTableExample extends JFrame {

  public JButtonTableExample() {
    super("JButtonTable Example");

    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { "button 1", "foo" },
        { "button 2", "bar" } }, new Object[] { "Button", "String","Edit" });

    JTable table = new JTable(dm);
    table.getColumn("Edit").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
    table.getColumn("Edit").setCellEditor(
        new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scroll);
    setSize(400, 100);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    JButtonTableExample frame = new JButtonTableExample();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }
}
/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */

class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

  public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }
}

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton("Edit");
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    return button;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
      // 
      // 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
      // System.out.println(label + ": Ouch!");
    }
    isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);
  }

  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }
}
```

Can any one suggest me where am wrong!!!
i didnt understand why button name was not coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are specifically setting the button's text to `""` here,

```
setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
```

in the `TableCellRenderer.getTableCellRenderer()` method. When a table is rendering, this method is called for each cell. And the value is set to `null`.

**To Fix use:**

```
setText((value == null) ? "Edit" : value.toString());
```

Comment: btw value==null ...but it should nt be null right as Im assigning as new Jbutton("Edit");

Comment: Oh Oh..sorry to say this its not working as expected.....on click it becoming as Edit....no this is not expected .....On load only i should see EDIT

Comment: Then it means you have changed the line on `ButtonEditor` class as well. Change it only in `ButtonRenderer` class.

Comment: Woooow..yup ur right....ur really awesome..thats right....btw why defalut value Edit is not coming as Im setting in creation of object only right???

Comment: No... The value should be specified in your dm.setDataVector() call. Use `{ "button 1", "foo", "button text" }` in that call and you will see `button text` on the button. Since you have given only `{ "button 1", "foo")`, it takes the 3rd column as null.

Comment: Ur just master of it....I m very much aprreciate for all ur pointers,...seriously you are too good...thanks a lot man..thats the right reason i got it